# How to install pywinauto-recorder.exe?

Tags: pywinauto

Not able to find the exe to install pywinauto-recorder for windows. Where can I find it ?

How can I install pywinauto recorder using .exe file but not from command prompt using pip install pywinauto because after installing from command prompt I am not able to open recorder.

The download button in https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/ redirects to 404 not found page. So not really sure where to get it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the author's cloud share link is down.

You can refer to the [doc](https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#:%7E:text=Double%20click%20on%20%E2%80%9Cpywinauto_recorder.exe_%E2%80%9D%20or%20run%20%E2%80%9Cpython.exe%20pywinauto_recorder.py%E2%80%9D%20to%20start%20the%20recorder.) and download the repo and start it with `python.exe pywinauto_recorder.py`

```
# Clone the repo
git clone https://github.com/beuaaa/pywinauto_recorder.git

# Setup .venv and enable it
pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv --python=python .venv
.\.venv\Scripts\activate

# Start the recorder
python.exe pywinauto_recorder.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The automatic generation of the documentation no longer worked and the link to download the installer was broken. Now it's been fixed and everything works normally.

You can find the installer on the main page of the documentation:

https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/

Click on the first big green button ("Click here to DOWNLOAD")